# Why was this "coding with Microsoft Paint" question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Why was [How did this person code "Hello World" with Microsoft Paint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588649/coding-with-microsoft-paint/5588672#5588672) closed as NARQ?

It was an objective question with a straightforward answer. Perhaps it belongs on Super User rather than Stack Overflow, as it's more about creating a text file, rather than programming, but none of the close voters posted a comment about why it was closed.

**Update:** It's since been re-opened.

Comment: IMHO, that would have been a safer question to ask here on Meta.  While I don't think it's NARQ, it has an off-topic Meta feel to it.

Comment: @John: absolutely not suitable for Meta (why would it be - how does it relate to the SE engine or environment?), and not suitable for SU either, FWIW.

Comment: @Micheal: I can't see the picture, but it is my understanding that he's searching for a specific question.  If search failed him or if the question was deleted, IMHO that's very appropriate for Meta.

Comment: @John: Naw. That's just a standard "apologies for the possible dupe" comment. If that was a criteria for moving a post to Meta, we'd see several hundred thousand more posts here.

Comment: @Micheal: I guess it's just a matter of opinion. (S&A, anyone?)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm re update: [It was reopened by Joel.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5588649/revisions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't have been; that was a legit programming question.

Comment: Exactly, it seemed to have been closed just because it was a reference to an answer to a joke question.

Answer (score 2):

I edited it so it'll hopefully stay open this time.

At least part of the reason it was closed was that it wasn't written well, and no one took the time to edit it.

Comment: Imagine that...

Comment: @Robert It just amazes me that with the tools in place, there are still lots of rubber-neckers, but very few people that actually get out and help. It's somewhat disturbing.